# pi4 no module named gpio

Tags: python, rpi.gpio

I am trying to `import rpi.gpio` in my geany on pi4,
but it comes with error no module named `gpio`.
The odd is that i updated pip and python and installed successfully with `sudo apt-get install python3-rpi.gpio` (feedback:python3-rpi.gpio is already the newest version 0.7.0-buster. 0 upg,0 new inst,0 rem,73 not upgraded).I installed dev also.
I will appreciate any help

Comment: Did you get the case right: 'import RPi.GPIO'. Have a look at examples that are available all over the web...

Comment: Ah, let me see. My Rpi4 Raspbian 10 buster Thorny python 3.7.3  "import RPi.GPIO as GPIO" is OK. No complaints. :)

Answer (score 5):

You should import the GPIO library as `import RPi.GPIO as GPIO` than reference it by using `GPIO`.

Also packages for python 3.x require you to use `pip3 install` rather than `sudo apt-get install python3-rpi.gpio` as it doesn't require elevated privileges and has access to the python package index ([pypi.org](https://pypi.org))